# FInd a character in a string in column in dataframe and give decisions in R

Tags: r, substring

I have data in following format

```
     Loss        
--------------------------
     R0RKE         
     R0HKE
```

I want R script to return me after applying logic: If 3rd character in string
is 'R' then Yes, if its 'H' then No, else leave blank

```
           Loss
--------------------------
           Yes
           No
```

Comment: Try `ifelse(substr(df$Loss, 3,3)=='R', 'Yes', ifelse(substr(df$Loss, 3,3)=='H', 'No', ''))`

Answer (score 1):

Regex way...

```
x <- c("RORKE","ROHKE", "FIVE")
ifelse(sub("^..(.).*", "\\1", x) == "R", "Yes", ifelse(sub("^..(.).*", "\\1", x) == "H", "No", " "))
# [1] "Yes" "No"  " "
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `substr` along with `recode` from `library(car)`.  We extract the third character of elements in the 'Loss' column using `substr`, then `recode` the 'R' to 'Yes', 'H' to 'No' and all others to `''`.

```
library(car)
recode(substr(df$Loss,3,3), "'R'='Yes'; 'H'='No'; else=''")
#[1] "Yes" "No"  ""    "Yes" ""
```

---

Or a `base R` option is `substr/match/factor`.  We extract the third character with `substr` ('v1'), `match` with the letters 'R', 'H' to get the numeric index ('v2'), convert to `factor` by specifying the `labels` for the corresponding `levels` and reconvert it to `character`.

```
v1 <- substr(df$Loss,3,3)
v2 <- match(v1, c('R', 'H'), nomatch=0)
as.character(factor(v2, levels=0:2, labels=c('', 'Yes', 'No')))
#[1] "Yes" "No"  ""    "Yes" ""
```

#### data

```
df <-  data.frame(Loss= c('RORKE', 'ROHKE', 'RODKE', 'RDRKD', NA))
```